# Symfony/doctrine: can't login database user, something not right in security.yml?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

For the past few days I've been struggling with logging in a database-user using Symfony/Doctrine, and I'm pretty stuck by now (I'm new to Symfony, btw). I got the login working using the in_memory provider (to start with), but now I want to login using a database-user and I just don't know what's wrong.

I went over the documentation over and over and I think I got everything right. I don't get errors, it just says "Invalid credentials." when I try to login. I have to feeling that it has something to do with security.yml but I've tried about all I could find. Below is my code;

security.yml;

```
security:
providers:
    provider_users:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: username

encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: provider_users
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

User.php;

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AppBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="string")
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        //
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set roles
     *
     * @param string $roles
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = json_encode($roles);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get roles
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return json_decode($this->roles);
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
}
```

I also tested if I could just get the user "manually" using getRepository()->findAll(), and that looks okay;

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
    object(AppBundle\Entity\User)[323]
      private 'id' => int 20
      private 'username' => string 'user' (length=4)
      private 'salt' => string 'mqshzqa9syok0kw8ss4cscc84k4k804' (length=31)
      private 'password' => string 'user1' (length=5)
      private 'email' => string 'user@localhost.com' (length=18)
      private 'roles' => string '' (length=0)
      private 'isActive' => boolean true

success!
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The password in the db is plain text, but should be bcrypt hashed

Comment: Like JimL said, on registration you need to encode your password with bcrypt. Your password looks like plain text.

Comment: Thank you guys, that seems like a logical explanation. I'll look into it and if when I fix it I'll post a solution!

Answer (score 1):

you need to encrypt the password with bcrypt. Possibly the user was in the database before adding security. Try to add another user with the encrypted password in php have for example: string crypt (string $ str [, string $ salt ] )

The string that you insert in the password field User :
user-> setPassword ('your encrypted string')

Comment: Yes, you're right, I add it "manually" so the password isn't encrypted at all. Thanks for the examples, I'll try them out!

Comment: Hey, I've tried encrypting the password in php, but unfortunately it didn't work... They're encrypted in the db, yet, but when I try to login I still get the error "Invalid credentials". I used;

$this->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());

Any more suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Hey!, I think the documentation will help:http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#dynamically-encoding-a-password

If it does not work , try using dump () before and after encrypting the password for comparison . Note that the password in the database should these encrypted , if you still have the password in plain text, encriptala and update the DB . Sorry for not being able to help more